# RestKit Authentication with Multiple Parameters

Tags: http, authentication, restkit

I have trouble getting authentication to work with a REST API that I have on a PHP stack. The query string that allows login to work on a browser looks something like http://foo.com/gamer/index.php?module=Login&action=myLogin... I followed every available documentation on RestKit and came up with the following code, in addition to enabling the NSLogConfigure, the output of which follows the code.
Code

```
- (void)sendHTTPAuthRequestWithParams {
NSMutableDictionary* authParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary* moreParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//user and password params
[authParams setObject:usernameTextField.text forKey:@"login"];
[authParams setObject:passwordTextField.text forKey:@"password"];

//more parameters for rest login api
[moreParams setObject:@"Login" forKey:@"module"];
[moreParams setObject:@"mylogin" forKey:@"action"];
[moreParams setObject:authParams forKey:@"params"];

//parsing
id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *json = [parser stringFromObject:moreParams error:&error];

[RKClient sharedClient].authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTP;

//if no error
if(!error) {        
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/index.php?" params:[RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON] delegate:self];  
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
}    
//[[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/index.php?module=Login&action=mylogin" params:authParams delegate:self];   }
```

RKLogConfigureByName() Output

```
    2012-05-24 19:59:09.513 GiantsGamer[57045:207] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:435 Sending asynchronous POST request to URL http://www.foo.com/gamer/index.php. 
2012-05-24 19:59:09.514 GiantsGamer[57045:207] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:381 Prepared POST URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest http://localhost/gamer/index.php>'. HTTP Headers: {
"Content-Length" = 85; "Content-Type" = "application/json";}. HTTP Body: {"module":"Login","action":"mylogin","params":{"login":"admin","password":"admin"}}. 2012-05-24 19:59:09.736 GiantsGamer[57045:207] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:195 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 200 2012-05-24 19:59:09.737 GiantsGamer[57045:207] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:196 Headers: {"Cache-Control" = "no-store, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 2745;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 25 May 2012 02:59:09 GMT";
    Expires = "";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Pragma = "";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8";
    "Set-Cookie" = "PIWIK_SESSID=a065dba239819175689b1e2a23021d01; path=/; HttpOnly";
    "X-Frame-Options" = sameorigin;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.8";
}
2012-05-24 19:59:09.737 GiantsGamer[57045:207] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:203 Read response body: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>…
</head>
<body>...
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the log, the query string (authentication parameters) are included in the HTTP body. Is that fine? Also, I do get the http response status code 200 (OK), but then I just see the entire HTML code produced by the webpage at index.html. Not sure where I am going wrong? How do I decipher the RestKit response?

Comment: Have you tried sending all your params as a simple string on the path variable? What do you get as a response with that?

Comment: I tried doing that, and that worked fine... however, I had to hardcode authentication values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are sending module and action as POST values instead of GET. You are probably receiving the same html code as if you would make a request to index.php without params. If you want, you could try your code and capture the whole HTML response and compare it with the index.php HTML response on the web, without params, I bet that they are the same.

I haven't tested this code but give it a try:

```
- (void)sendHTTPAuthRequestWithParams {

    NSString *loginPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"index.php?module=%@&action=%@",@"Login",@"myModule"];

    NSMutableDictionary* authParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [authParams setObject:usernameTextField.text forKey:@"login"];
    [authParams setObject:passwordTextField.text forKey:@"password"];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:loginPath usingBlock:^(RKRequest *request) {
        request.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTP;
        request.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        request.params = authParams;
        request.delegate = self;
        request.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
            if (response.statusCode > 299) {
                //We got an error!
            }else {
                //Check Response Body to get Data!
            }
        };

    }];
}
```

On response body you will get an NSData, if you expect a json on the response you can transform that to an NSDictionary with this: [NSData to NSDictionary from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524602/how-to-convert-php-return-nsdata-into-nsdictionary/10777245#10777245)

The main disadvantage of RK is that it lacks on good documentation, here are some things you can look to understand some of the basics:

You can see another way, a bit more advanced, of doing what you want using RKObjectMapping with RestKit: [Making a post to API with RKParams and mapping the response with RKObjectMapping using RestKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760333/making-a-post-to-api-with-rkparams-and-mapping-the-response-with-rkobjectmapping/).

Finally, you can check this code also, it describes  how to [Do a simple json POST using RESTKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102262/do-a-simple-json-post-using-restkit)

Also you can ask the developers of RestKit on twitter. That have worked great for me, they answer really fast!.

Comment: Thanks, @clopez, this worked perfectly for me. I am still a little puzzled why my original piece of code didn't work. Yeah, I too think that RKObjectMapping should work for advanced queries.

Comment: I'll update my response to answer that, and if you like, remember tu up-vote my answer :)

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question? How do you include a multi-form, an image in NSMutableDictionary? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189120/include-image-using-nsmutabaledictionary-with-rkclient-and-receiving-on-the-php/11190451#comment14704769_11190451