# Include image using NSMutabaleDictionary with RKClient and receiving on the Php Server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rest, restkit

1 - How can I include a picture using NSMutableDictionary with RestKit Client?

My server receives data from NSMutableDictionary in my code below.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:usernameTextfield.text forKey:@"username"];

[client put:@"/main/insert" params:params delegate:self];
```

but how can I attach an image at the same time?

On the other hand, RKParams doesn't work for me on my server side.

```
RKParams *params=[[RKParams alloc]init];
imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageField.image);
[params setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/png" forParam:@"image"];
```

Rest server code:

```
public function insert_put()
{
    $username = $this->put('username');

    $this->model->insertPost($username);

    //Question number 2.        

    $data['success'] = 'added successfully';
    $this->response($data, 200);
}
```

2 - How can I receive it from my server(php) ? I'm using put option to this.

Comment: hi..will you take a look again? Updated question

Answer (score 0):

Your RestKit code looks fine, I think it is your php code that is failing. RestKit will upload the image as part of a multipart/form-data. This info will not appear in your normal _PUT array like your username did. I'm not sure what frameworks you are using (Is that the REST Controller library?), but you can access the file using _FILES['image'] or whatever your server framework uses. $this->files('image') maybe?

EDIT:

To create a mixed param file try this:

```
NSDictionary* strings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: usernameTextfield.text, @"username", nil];
NSData* image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
RKParams* params = [[RKParams alloc] initWithDictionary: strings];
[params setData: image MIMEType: @"image/png" withParameter: @"image"];

//And send it
[client put:@"/main/insert" params:params delegate:self];
```

But now you can not use $this->put, but instead $this->upload. For example:

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
$username = $data['username'];
$imagefile = $data['image'];
```

Comment: Yup, its REST Controller. RKParams don't work with $this->put('username'); in my server but the NSMutableDictionary does. Is there a way I can attach image with NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: I modified the code, but I am not very familiar with codeigniter. No, don't put the image in the dictionary it is not the problem.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Only the NSMutableDictionary works for me.
What do you think is the problem?

Comment: The problem is almost definitely on your server side. I don't know your framework well enough to comment more. You need to find how to extract data from a multipart/form-data field with your framework.

Comment: I tried to use insert_post and it worked for RKParams. The only problem now is how to get the image. I tried $this->files, $_FILES and the one you suggested above, non of them worked. Always get Undefined index:  image, Undefined index:  username.

Answer (score 0):

I just do the following

```
- (void) upload: (UIImage *) pic onLoad:(RKObjectLoaderDidLoadObjectBlock) loadBlock onError:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock{

    RKParams* imageParams = [RKParams params];
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic, 0.7f);
    [imageParams setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpg" forParam:@"FileUpload"];
    NSString *resourcePath = @"/api/upload/";

    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[KFMedia class]];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        loader.params = imageParams;
        [self settingsForLoader:loader withMapping:mapping onLoad:loadBlock onError:failBlock];

    }];

}

- (void) settingsForLoader: (RKObjectLoader *) loader withMapping: (RKObjectMapping *) mapping onLoad:(RKObjectLoaderDidLoadObjectBlock) loadBlock onError:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock{

    loader.objectMapping = mapping;
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.onDidLoadObject = loadBlock;

    loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError * error){
       //NSLog(@"%@",error);
    };
    loader.onDidFailLoadWithError = failBlock;
    loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
        [self fireErrorBlock:failBlock onErrorInResponse:response];
    };

}
```